# What mathematical branch doesn't use the definition of function?

Tags: functions, foundations

Every branch of mathematics I've seen so far works with sets and functions as core building blocks for its definitions.

What's a branch in math that use functions very little or maybe not at all?

Pardon if this question is too meta for this site, if so tell me where it fits better.

Note: This is not about me being uncomfortable about the definition. It's more that I learned about functions in middle school and back then didn't realize at all what scope of uses this definition comprises, but I still can't really pinpoint what was missing in my view. Habituation is not the same as understanding apparently.

Comment: Well, "sets" and "functions" are somewhat different things. Do you care about one more than the other? "Sets" are a not-truly-essential foundational idea. "Functions" are more of an operational idea... Can you clarify?

Comment: There are branches of mathematics which don't use much of the abstract machinery of set theory, but there is no branch of mathematics that I've ever heard of which doesn't use the concept of a function.

Comment: Maybe if you restrict to some weak theory like one based on Euclid's axioms for geometry, where the only concepts are points, lines, angles and circles.

Comment: It's harder not to work with functions than working with them, for sure. Usually, functions come to simplify arguments. For now, I would suggest asking some context to your question. What you are studying and why you want to question about it. What aspects of functions and sets make you feel uncomfortable?

Comment: It's important to note that Euclid's geometry is not as complete as the geometry made in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I've always thought it would be a good idea to questions the foundations of what you know. Why do we always use functions i.e. something that for each input gives us one output, rather than two outputs for each input? Or why should we be doing a "correspondence between objects" in the first place? Or why do we accept that sets are an important structure rather than other possible structure types? But it seems that I never find the time to explore these ideas further, probably due to bad time management in general...

Comment: One of the main organizing principles of contemporary mathematics is that one should not only consider classes of objects, but also appropriate morphisms between them (in the sense of category theory), which are typically functions of some sort. So I think that what you are looking for does not really exist.

Comment: Classical geometry doesn't use functions.  But all of the rest of them have some sort of "morphisms" which have function-like properties.  Linear algebra works with "linear transformations."   Abstract Algebra has groups and group homomorphisms.

Comment: @AdamRubinson exactly. I feel like I don't *really* know what I'm doing. I guess we can only know what we're doing, not what we're missing but should be doing instead.